# document.getelementbyID option not available

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I try to use JavaScript and when I try to find this :

```
document.getElementbyID
```

It is not there in my listbox .

Comment: The function's name is `getElementById`, which you can find out by reading the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Comment: First of all thank you. I am sorry if i could not convey properly. This option is not available at all. In Eclipse ( Helios ), when i do "document." There is no option with getelement at all...

Comment: And did you try to run the code despite that?

Comment: Ah, i forcibly wrote entered the code . It gave me an error. I think i am missing something here like some libraries possibly. a simple java code or a simple Selenium code works. But not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this with a cabital b:

document.getElementByID

Comment: And with a lowercase `d`.

Comment: First of all thank you. I am sorry if i could not convey properly. This option is not available at all. In Eclipse ( Helios ), when i do "document." There is no option with getelement at all...

Comment: @SriharshaKaranth Are you working with Java or Javascript? Usually, people don't code for the web with Eclipse...

Comment: Oh ok. Im working with Java. I use Java for my Selenium Automation Tool. In Some of the cases , Selenium's Java commands would not work.So in these cases i use Javascript. I can tell you a scnario where in the elemnts were hidden in the page.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can be fairly case sensitive(sorry cant add comments for some reason on phone)

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to post comments. You could answer the question properly though.

Comment: First of all thank you. I am sorry if i could not convery properly. This option is not available at all. In Eclipse ( Helios ), when i do "document." There is no option with getelement at all...

Comment: i can comment now. Idk that software, my apologies, but sometimes I have to type it in and it isnt found automatically especially asp.net front end and notepad, but if you can put in manually, it should work. You might need proper libraries.

Comment: No need to apologize . Thank you. will look for libraries as you gentlemen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't rely on intellisense to write the code for you. Often times what you're looking for won't show up (especially when using third party libraries such as jQuery). For what you want to do, if you're using JavaScript, you just need to format it properly. Try this:

`document.getElementById("YourElementId");`

YourElementId will be the ID of whatever element you're trying to interact with.

Comment: Thank you sir. But if i do it manually i get an error saying 'cant execute the code'. But a very interesting point. you said i need libraries for these javascripts to work? i will try and find these libraries.

Comment: No. You do not need libraries for JavaScript to work. What are you typing into? Your HTML or a external JavasScript file? I'm not exactly clear on what you're setup is. What is returning the 'cannot execute code' error?

Comment: ok. I have Eclipse - Helios version. Now im trying to write some Automated script for a web page . For this Automation purpose i use Selenium Automation tool. I have Java Installed on my machine. By default there is a mechanism in selenium to look for the objects in the webpage. Sometimes due to poor coding in the web page itself selenium would not work and we would need to use Javascript in that case.

Comment: `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;`
'String a = (String)js.executeScript(document.-->`                                 in this line if i do write 'document.getElementbyID(element)'. It would give me an error.

Comment: That was written by me . But if i just say document.      , the getelementbyID is not available.

Comment: Capitalize the 'b' in getElementbyId. IT NEEDS TO BE getElementById with a capital B

Comment: Ok i mean the intellisense which shows you once you put a dot (.) mark, that drop down does not contain the mentioned menthod which is - getElementById ( i nned to use it like this document.getElementById(element))